# Are there a budget way to make shoes to not slide at winter?

Tags: shoes, winter, walking

I've seen there's Canadian gadet for than - firm plastic base with metal crown-like spikes that you fixating under your boots. But they're expensive - about 90 bucks. I tried cheap from China, but they're not firm, they're soft made of silicone and my shoes they like dress shoes (like oxford or brogue type), they don't have thick rubber base as big boots or sneakers, **so I felt those cleats with my feet, walking was uncomfortable.**

Those 90 bucks and cheap ones they both looked like this:
[image]

And my shoes are like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi R S, Welcome to Lifehacks. "Ice cleats for shoes" fills a search page results with many of what you describe for < C$30 from various suppliers incl. Sports Experts and Canadian Tire, etc.

Comment: Not wearing dress shoes with thin leather soles out in wet, icy weather would be a good start. Why risk ruining relatively expensive footwear by using it for a task for which it was not designed? Consider using footwear appropriate for the conditions and carrying the inappropriate footwear so you can, eg swap them over when you get to work

Comment: How about using zip tie straps? Cheapest way possible. You can do the same on your bike too.

Comment: @CustomX unlikely, not enough friction.

Comment: @RS, You would be surprised how well it works. You need the thick part on the bottom though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need a two-step approach. I don't have a brand to recommend. I have a technique you might find helpful.

Keep your cheap cleats; but, put them on over a pair of rubber overshoes which will stiffen the soles and protect your polished shoes from wear and tear of the cleats rubbing against your dress shoes.

Step 1. Shoe protection

[image: Step 1. shoe protection]

Step 2. Put your anti-skid ice cleats on over these galoshes. More complete weather protection for your footwear. Stiffer soles for your foot comfort.

Answer (score 4):

Take some old socks, the more coarsly knitted the better, and pull them over your shoes.
It really works, people in Croatia and neighbouring countries sometimes do this in winter.

Anyway, you asked for cheap, not fashionable.

Answer (score 2):

I put the "webbed" side of Velcro on the bottom of mine. Just cut a long strip and attach it to each side of the shoe. I haven't had any problems sliding after that.

Also, I picked up a couple of packages of Non Slip Shoe Grip at my local Dollar Tree. They work great too. [image]

Comment: Hi Blaez, Welcome to Lifehacks.